# Debug log levels not sticky on SFDC version refresh

Tags: winter14

Just noticed this on Winter 14 sandboxes

- Go to **Monitoring | Debug Log | Filters**
- Change log levels (say Apex classes from default 'Debug' to 'Info'
- Save

Result

- Changed debug log levels are ignored and reset back to defaults
- Affects any test run from **Develop | Apex Test Execution | select test(s)**

I can workaround this by testing from Developer Console where the debug log levels can be changed and are sticky. No mention in Known Issues site

Comment: I didn't noticed on '14 sandboxes. I will check it. I think debug log filters are reset when you add user again to debug log request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the user in **Monitoring | Debug Log** and re-add.

The debug log filters will become sticky.

This must be an issue when you have a user U being monitored on Vx, SFDC introduces a new Vx+1, and you attempt to change filters on user U.  Deleting the logging for U and then re-adding U solves the issue.